# Why does having a subquery inside of an IN clause triggers a full scan while using an array doesn't?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, subquery

I have two BigQuery tables A (~100mb) and B (~69gb). Table A is partitioned by a date field and has multiple fields. Table B is not partitioned and only has one date field. I want to delete all records on table A that are within the partition dates on table B.

Using a subquery inside my delete where clause triggers a full scan of table B:

```sql
DELETE
FROM `table_B`
WHERE cdate IN (SELECT DISTINCT (cdate) FROM `table_A`)
```

In my BigQuery case, this processes ~69gb: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvLQD.png

However, if I write all dates as an array instead of using the subquery, then it only reads the specified partitions:

```sql
DELETE
FROM `table_B`
WHERE cdate IN ("2022-04-01","2022-04-02", "2022-04-03", ...)
```

In my BigQuery case, this processes ~12.5gb: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCSzu.png

I understand the subquery having the overhead of fetching the records from table A, but the 69gb of processing leads me to believe a full scan is happening on table B.

I've tried a couple of different things such as using a temporary table and a WITH statement, but same result. I don't want to resort to writing a procedural statement and manually constructing the array, that would be quite cumbersome, but I'm running out of options.

How is the the subquery evaluated? Is there a different way to accomplish what's happening on the second query that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you run the query and see the result in the logs (TotalByteBilled)? The DryRun can't suppose what you will get from the subquery (without running it!), so it will propose you the worse case. But at runtime, it's possible that is optimized, therefore if you look in the logs to see the true result.

Comment: I did try that, it processed the full 69gb unfortunately: https://i.imgur.com/VeJcieX.png.

Comment: In that case, dynamic queries can help you, but it's a script and in any case the dry run could help you in that task.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you mean dynamically generating the query with the array values? I'm avoiding that solution due to the possibility of having thousands of different values (in my example it's already ~250, which is a lot). An elegant solution would be better, but if I find nothing else I'll have to run with that.

Comment: Yes, dynamic query is a string creation followed by an execute immediate. And indeed your IN can be huge, but not bigger as you can have at runtime! That being said, I don't know how often you run your query, but 70Go it's not very large...

Comment: It's quite often, every 15 minutes actually! I'll wait to see if more solutions appear. Thanks!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, as expected, writing a dynamic query with BQ procedural language does work:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM `table_B` WHERE cdate IN ( '%s' )
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CAST(cdate AS STRING), "','") FROM `table_A`))
```

This in my BigQuery case processes 2kb to build the statement, and 12.5gb for the actual query, the same processing as typing in the dates in an array. This solves my issue, but I'd still like to understand how BigQuery evaluates the subquery, and if this is actually the only way to do it, as I find it far from elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In first query the subquery needs to be evaluated for each row in TableB the check whether the `cdate` is a match or not. This should be a very expensive operation in a large table.

You might get a better performance with `not exists`:

```
DELETE
FROM `table_B` b
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM `table_A` a
  WHERE a.cdate= b.cdate
)
```

Comment: I seems like processing increases with this method: https://i.imgur.com/8RfrRSO.png

Answer (score 0):

Using [PARTITIONS view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-partitions#schema) :

```sql
DELETE FROM `table_B` WHERE cdate IN (
   SELECT partition_id
     FROM `your-project-name.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
    WHERE table_schema = 'your_dataset' AND table_name = 'table_A'
 );
```

Or, you can try a dynamic SQL

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  DELETE FROM `table_B` WHERE cdate IN ('%s')
""", (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(partition_id, "','") 
    FROM `your-project-name.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
   WHERE table_schema = 'your_dataset' AND table_name = 'table_A'
));

-- or, without using PARTITIONS view.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  DELETE FROM `table_B` WHERE cdate IN ('%s')
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT cdate, "','") FROM `table_A`))
```

Comment: I see, the PARTITIONS view part wouldn't work for me as I'm not looking to delete from B the partitions in A, I'm looking to delete the partitions in B that match the values of the cdate column in A. The dynamic SQL part could be updated to do that using my original query, but I was avoiding it due to looking a bit hack-ish. If there are no alternatives I'll probably use that. Thank you for the response!